# What is the meaning of "No further exceptions"？

Tags: android, exception, rx-java, crashlytics, rx-java2

I integrated the rxJava and crashlytics in my develop android app.
But,I received a strange crash message on crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: io.reactivex.internal.util.ExceptionHelper$1: No further exceptions
```

This is an exception thrown by the rxjava，But I don't know what this means,
And log only this line.

rxjava and crashlytics version:

`rxjava: io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.4`

`crashlytics: com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5`

---

*EIDT:*

When I upgraded to rxjava 2.0.6, I got stacktrace:

> io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError (RxJavaPlugins.java:366)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.onError (ObservableFlatMap.java:290)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.drainLoop (ObservableFlatMap.java:368)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.drain (ObservableFlatMap.java:323)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.onComplete (ObservableFlatMap.java:300)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromArray$FromArrayDisposable.run (ObservableFromArray.java:110)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromArray.subscribeActual (ObservableFromArray.java:36)
>   io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:10700)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap.subscribeActual (ObservableFlatMap.java:55)
>   io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:10700)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap.subscribeActual (ObservableFlatMap.java:55)
>   io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:10700)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableBuffer.subscribeActual (ObservableBuffer.java:44)
>   io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:10700)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap.subscribeActual (ObservableFlatMap.java:55)
>   io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:10700)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromObservable.subscribeActual (FlowableFromObservable.java:31)
>   io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe (Flowable.java:12901)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnBackpressureBuffer.subscribeActual (FlowableOnBackpressureBuffer.java:45)
>   io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe (Flowable.java:12901)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMap.subscribeActual (FlowableFlatMap.java:52)
>   io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe (Flowable.java:12901)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableTakeUntil.subscribeActual (FlowableTakeUntil.java:37)
>   io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe (Flowable.java:12901)
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run (FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
>   io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run (ScheduledRunnable.java:59)
>   io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call (ScheduledRunnable.java:51)
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
>   java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)

Now I can start to analyze the source of the crash.

Comment: please provide some code on how you integrate the libraries

Comment: That exception may happen due to bugs in RxJava operators not detecting some terminal conditions and trying to emit multiple errors. I believe when you upgrade to RxJava 2.0.6 you should get a more telling stacktrace. Any information on what your flows do or what operators you are using would be very helpful.

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks a lot,as you said, I can get more information on the crashlytics to help analyze the problem when I upgraded to rxjava 2.0.6.

Comment: Thanks for the stacktrace, it is a bug in flatMap. Fix in  https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/5188

Comment: Had the strange exception with Rx Java 2.2.8 as well. I had a flatmapComplete operator wrapped into a flatmapComplete operator. After replacing this with a flatmap followed by a flatmapComplete the error seems to have disappeared. Is say "seems" as the error happened sporadically.